# While implementing IEnumerable<T>, pointer misdirection is observed

Tags: c#-4.0

This is an interesting error I've come across while implementing IEnumerable on a class.  It appears to be similar to an "access to modified closure" issue, but I'm at a loss as to how to fix it.

Here is a simple example that demonstrates the issue:

```
void Main()
{
    var nodeCollection = new NodeCollection();
    nodeCollection.MyItems = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };

    foreach (var node in nodeCollection)
    {
        node.Dump();
    }
}

public class NodeCollection : IEnumerable<Node>
{
    public List<string> MyItems;

    public IEnumerator<Node> GetEnumerator()
    {
        // This isn't necessary, but it should prove that it's not an "access to modified closure" issue.
        var items = MyItems;
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            var node = new Node();

            // I want the node to contains the items in MyItems.
            node.Items = items;

            // Plus an additional item.  Note that I am adding the item to the node, NOT to MyItems.
            node.Items.Add(string.Format("iteration: {0}", i));

            yield return node;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}

public class Node
{
    public List<string> Items;
}
```

As you can see from the `Dump()` statement, I'm running this in LINQPad, but the issue will present itself in any IDE.

When I run the snippet, I get the following output:

[image: Snippet Result]

Because I am adding the item to `Items` in the newly instantiated `Node`, I would NOT expect the item to be added to `MyItems`, but this is obviously what is occurring.

It seems that `Items` in `Node` is pointing to `MyItems` in `NodeCollection`.

Can anyone tell me:

- Why this is happening?
- How to make it not happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating new nodes each iteration, but then setting the same `items` instance to the `Items` property of each node. Then you are adding the iteration string to the items instance stored in the Items collection (which is always the same instance), resulting in each subsequent node having more and more "iteration" entries.  If you kept all of the nodes, you'd find that all of them have exactly the same `Items` value.

I think the basic misunderstanding here was that you were assuming that setting the Items property of the Node (`node.Items = items;`) would copy the `items` list into the node.  In fact, all it does is set node.Items to point to the already-existing list that you call `items`.

This should give you an idea where you went wrong:

```
    // This same instance of items is being reused each time
    var items = MyItems;
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        var node = new Node();

        // I want the node to contains the items in MyItems.
        // Assuming node.Items is a List<String>
        node.Items = new List<String>();
        node.Items.AddRange(items);
        node.Items.Add(string.Format("iteration: {0}", i));

        yield return node;
    }
```

Comment: This is why I love SO; something that is completely baffling to me is obvious to others.  I still don't quite understand the behavior, give me a few minutes...

Comment: See my update in the middle of the comment, "I think the basic misunderstanding here..."

Comment: That makes sense, for some reason I was thinking that it was copying the list rather than pointing to the existing one.

Answer (score 2):

`node.Items = items;` sets `node.Items` to be a reference to the `items` list. There is just one list, with several references to it.

I suppose that what you want is to have a separate list in each node and that you want to copy the elements in `items` into that list. To do that, create a new list wich contains all of the elements from `items`.

```
node.Items = new List<string>(items);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do:
           var item = MyItems;
you just create a reference to MyItems and store it in the variable item. Then when you do:
           node.Items = items;
you just take the same reference and store it in node.Items. If you need node.Items to be a new list (point to a different memory location) initialize it again.
           node.Items = new List();